# Duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted

Tags: mysql

Im getting error for my stored procedure...any idea for how to solve it ?

PROCEDURE is as below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prc_medic_check_status(v_task_id IN VARCHAR, v_request_id IN VARCHAR, v_task_desc IN VARCHAR, v_task_status IN VARCHAR) IS v_task_id task.task_id%TYPE;

v_request_id task.request_id%TYPE;

v_medical_id Varchar(30);

v_medical_status Varchar(30);

BEGIN
SELECT request_id INTO v_request_id
FROM Request
WHERE request_type = "Medical";


SELECT task_id INTO v_task_id
FROM task
WHERE request_id = v_request_id ;


SELECT medical_status INTO v_medical_status
FROM Medical m,
     medicalRequest mr,
     Request r
WHERE mr.request_id = r.request_id
  AND mr.medical_id = m.medical_id;

IF (v_medical_status = "Available") THEN
UPDATE Task
SET task_status = "Done"`enter code here
WHERE request_id = v_request_id;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Medical Task Done');

ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Medical Task Not Done');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Due To The Medical Product Is Currently Not Available');

END IF;

END;
```

/

Comment: What error are you getting? Please, provide more details

Comment: Errors: PROCEDURE PRC_MEDIC_CHECK_STATUS

Line: 1 PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted

Line: 0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter variables are defined as a local variable in the stored procedure thus the error.  Usually, we use p_* for passing parameters so I strongly suggest you define your stored procedure as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prc_medic_check_status(p_task_id IN VARCHAR, p_request_id IN VARCHAR, p_task_desc IN VARCHAR, p_task_status IN VARCHAR)
```

Then change the new parameter names in your query:

```
SELECT task_id INTO v_task_id 
FROM task 
WHERE request_id = p_request_id ;
```

Comment: yeah the duplication error is gone. Thanks.

But there is another error, its shows that Error at Line:73 ....but my procedure has only 34 line...not sure why.

Btw im using Oracle Live SQL

Comment: It is hard to debug your procedure without sample data to work on. If you like my previous answer, please accept it then we can work on the rest of the issues.

Comment: Ok accepted. So you want me to send all my create table and insert values to you ?